# How can I know the Name of the "IAM role" attached to EC2 using PowerShell from EC2 Instance itself?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

I have an EC2 instance (EC2_Windows_2019_Server_Test) which is attached to an "IAM role".

How can I know the Name of the "IAM role" attached to EC2 using PowerShell from EC2 Instance itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @maafk.

```bsh
$instanceRole = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Powershell you should be able to get from the EC2 instance metadata

```bsh
$instanceRole = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials")
```

Can find a list of available metadata [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html)

Comment: Thanks @maafk for input. I did a small update (removed `role-name` from the URL) to your script and it worked. So the working script is: $instanceRole = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/role-name")

Comment: A more streamlined command would be `Invoke-RestMethod http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials`